# Apply CSS style dynamically in row Angular Material Table, based on click method

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8

thanks for your support. Currently I'm struggling with some issues. So, I'm trying to make a dynamically rows into Angular Mat Table. Making a toogle effect between labels and inputs. My goal is to update and delete data, from specific row.

I'm almost done, but when I click the button, all the rows are affected. I tried some logic with index, I  also used "data attribute" ([attr.data-example]), & I tried with ng-class. Let me explain with images, also I'll attach my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="example-table-container">

      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 tbl-header">
        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="usr_id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Usr ID </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="user">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Usuario </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span *ngIf="!isVisible">{{element.username}} </span>
            <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'eye-unselec': !isVisible, 'eye-selec': isVisible }" class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="editName" *ngIf="isVisible" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="rol">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Rol </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span *ngIf="!isVisible">{{element.rol}} </span>
            <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'eye-unselec': !isVisible, 'eye-selec': isVisible }" class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="editRol" *ngIf="isVisible" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="create_date">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fecha Alta </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.creationDate}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Estatus </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span *ngIf="!isVisible">{{element.status}}</span>
            <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'eye-unselec': !isVisible, 'eye-selec': isVisible }" class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="editStatus" *ngIf="isVisible" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="operaci">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Operaciones </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sns-btn edit" (click)="edit(element,i);isVisible=!isVisible">
              <fa-icon [icon]="editIcon" size="1x"></fa-icon>
            </button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="operaci2">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary sns-btn edit" (click)="delete()">
              <fa-icon [icon]="delIcon" size="1x"></fa-icon>
            </button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr [attr.row_status]="row.id |json" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

        <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
          <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```
public edit(element, i) {
 //if the inputs of each row of table are still blank, return to labels is allowed
 //this.isVisible = true; //show inputs

 if (this.editRol || this.editName || this.editStatus) {
   this.isVisible = false;
 }
 console.log(" index value " + i + "element " + JSON.stringify(element));
}
```

```
.eye-unselec{
  display: none;
}

.eye-selec {
  display: inline;
}
```

This is one example, but I have different things.

Here's [a link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4hgkz%20file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

IMAGES:
[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a boolean array instead of just a boolean, and use the index you already have as parameter to the edit function:

*app.component.ts*

```
isVisible : boolean[] = [false, false, false, false];

editDomain(index){
    this.isVisible[index] = true;
  }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="domain.name" *ngIf="isVisible[i]"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editDomain(i)">Edit</button>
```